# Python: What Does train() Method in Pybrain Package Return?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, pybrain

The link [here](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/training.html) says that `trainer.train()` returns

> a double proportional to the error

What does that mean? I am using `BackpropTrainer` to train a neural network for classification. So far, my code has returned values less than 1. Does it mean that it validates the training data and returns ratio of number of misclassified samples to the total samples?

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the documentation](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/training.html) it seems that it trains on the data for one epoch. It may be that it doesn't converge in that time, so it returns the mismatch (error).

`trainer.trainUntilConvergence()` will train on multiple epochs until it converges. It returns a tuple of each convergence mismatch.

Comment: When you say "mismatch(error)", do you mean ratio of number of misclassified samples to the total samples? Because I did not understand what "a double proportional to the error" means.

Comment: I have no knowledge of [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) other than what I just looked up for you. I imagine, for different networks, all tolerances are scaled to be unitless so that roughly for any network you can have an idea of how close to converged it is. So the absolute error will be related to the data in the network, but the scaled error will always be between -1 and +1, for example. I don't know though, just guessing.